What is Nial Ferguson trying to highlight in this lines?
I am reading Nial Ferguson's The ascent of money and in this paragraph, he compares the Argentine GDP to the US's:

The economic history of Argentina in the twentieth century is an object lesson that all the resources in the world can be set at nought by financial mismanagement. Particularly after the Second World War the country consistently underperformed its neighbours and most of the rest of the world. So miserably did it fare in the 1960s and 1970s, for example, that its per capita GDP was the same in 1988 as it had been in 1959. By 1998 it had sunk to 34 per cent of the US level, compared with 72 per cent in 1913. It had been overtaken by, among others, Singapore, Japan, Taiwan, and South Korea – not forgetting, most painful of all, the country next door, Chile.

Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (pp. 101-102). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
I cannot understand why he would compare the 34% in 1998 to the 72% in 1913 when indeed, such a comparison shows improvement through the years in Argentina's GDP compared to the US's when he is actually trying to criticize the Argentinian economy falling behind.
What is the purpose behind mentioning such data in this way? Might someone please redirect me to the right StackExchange site to ask this question?

In 1913, Argentina's GDP was equal to 72% of the US's, while in 1998 it was 34%. Say the US's GDP is $100 in both years. Then in 1913, Argentina's was $72, while in 1998, it was $34. The point is, Argentina's economy has become weaker relative to the US's. In words: In 1913, Argentina's GDP was equal to over two thirds of the US's GDP. In 1998, it was just one third.

@George K. Thank you! I really don't know what I got it all wrong from what I can understand if something had sunk to a certain level, it means that such a thing sank to that particular level, in this case from 100 % of US economy to 34% of that same economy, in other words, it had a decline of 66% to that economy so that is why when he said "relative to 72% in 1913" I reasoned that the Argentinian economy had had a decline of 72 % to the US economy, but I got it all wrong, I have not had good sleep recently.

@GeorgeK. Please don't answer in comments. I don't think this is possible: In 1913, Argentina's GDP was equal to over two thirds of the US's GDP.

@GeorgeK. - that's a good comment.

The reference is not to GDP but to per capita GDP.  I think it is quite possible that in 1913 Argentina's per capita GDP was 72% of the US's.

GDP is usually per capita.

@Lambie - but not always. UK GDP in 2023 was 2.72 trillion pounds, it was stated in parliament, and I can assure you that I didn't get that!

What has this got to do with the English language? Since it's about interpreting economic statistics, surely it belongs on Economics SE?

I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about learning English

Let's explore Argentina's economic performance as discussed in Niall Ferguson's The Ascent of Money:
I. GDP Definition:
Gross Domestic Product (GDP) measures the total value of goods and services produced within a country annually. It is a key indicator of economic activity.
GDP per capita is a measure of a country's economic output per person, calculated by dividing the country's gross domestic product (GDP) by its population.
II. Relative GDP per capita Calculation (Argentina vs. U.S.)
The percentages (72% in 1913 and 34% in 1998) reflect Argentina’s GDP per capita as a share of U.S. GDP per capita:
The calculation:
Relative GDP per capita = (Argentina's GDP per capita / U.S. GDP per capita) × 100
Expressing ratios in percentages simplifies comparisons by expressing one value as a proportion of another on a scale of 100, making changes easier to visualize.
For example, here we  understand Argentina’s GDP per capita was nearly three-quarters of the U.S.'s in 1913 but dropped to about one-third by 1998.

III. Argentina in 1913.
During the first three decades of the 20th century, Argentina outgrew Canada and Australia in population, total income, and per capita income.
By 1913, Argentina was among the world's ten wealthiest states per capita


IV. 1959-1998 Post–World War II economic expansion.
The post–World War II economic expansion, also known as the postwar economic boom or the Golden Age of Capitalism, was a broad period of worldwide economic expansion beginning with the aftermath of World War II.
The United States, the Soviet Union and Western European and East Asian countries in particular experienced unusually high and sustained growth, together with full employment.


Between 1959 and 1998, Argentina's per capita GDP stagnated (0% growth), while other countries experienced significant growth:

USA: ~100%
Japan, Singapore, South Korea, Taiwan: 500–600%
Chile: 200–300%

This comparison highlights Argentina’s missed opportunities during a global economic boom.

I read the comment -  "I reasoned that the Argentinian economy had had a decline of 72 % to the US economy". It only means in 1913 it was 72% and in 1998 it was 34%. (calculated as given above)

By 1998 it [Argentinian GDP] had sunk to 34 per cent of the US level, compared with 72 per cent in 1913.



By 1998, the Argentine GDP was at 34% of US GDP.




In 1913, the Argentine GDP was 72% of US GDP.



For example, to make this easy, let's say:
1a) US GDP was $1,000,000 in 1998. 34% of that = $340,000
2a) US GDP was $500,000 in 1913.   72% of $10,000 = $360,00
As a percentage, 34% is less than 72%, or 72% is greater than 34%,  regardless of the actual amounts. So as a percentage of US GDP, Argentine GDP went down.
GDP's are compared to show standard of living (all things remaining equal).
It is common to use GDP as a measure of economic welfare or standard of living in a nation.
standard of living
The Ferguson text does not go into detail here, but the idea is that Argentina's standard of living has gone down.
[My answer was revised. The first one was wrong.]

I rarely downvote, but this answer is completely incorrect.  With 1998 GDP of 9.06t for the US and 299b for Argentina, and populations of 276m and 36.2m, respectively, we get per-capita GDP of $32,800 for the US and $8,260 for Argentina.  This puts the per-capita GDP of Argentina at 25% that of the US--not quite the same as Ferguson's number, but in the right ball park.
The 1913 numbers are more challenging, but this answer tries to take them from a help page for a board game (1/2).

A historical board game, but a game nonetheless.  Not a reliable reference for historical economic data.  Then, the 'gdp' values quoted out of that page are not from the 'gdp' column, but from the 'percentage of (game) world economy' column, leading to a calculation based on dividing two numbers from a game that don't even purport to be GDP.

@user4556274 The 1913: This list is based upon The Wor[l]d Economy by Angus Maddison. I have adjusted the figures to reflect pre-WW1 boundaries. Colonies are included with the ruling nation. However, most British areas in the Middle East were actually protectorates and listed separately. The amounts are in billions of 1990 dollars. The figures have some problems because they are based upon modern boundaries and it is unclear whether the GDP represents the modern borders or historical borders.

The World Economy
A Millennial Perspective
OECD Development Centre Angus Maddison is associated with the OECD.
